# How to convert String to Date in java

Tags: java, string, date-format, simpledateformat

I have a string something like date month year(31 08 2012) . I want to convert it to date format.

```
String string = "31082012";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("DDMMYYYY").parse(string);
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Change `DDMMYYYY` to `ddMMyyyy`, see [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)

Comment: Why so many downvotes ?? Poor guy lost his 10 rep ! Be nice guys :)

Comment: Have you read the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?

Comment: What the hell happening,why so many down votes ?????

Comment: Questions like this have been asked a plenty of times here. Most of them could be answered by reading the documentation.

Comment: @RJ. because, it is a very basic question. you can find the answer just by lookin at the API .:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, Your format is wrong, it should be `ddMMyyyy`

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").parse(string);
```